# Mobilefirst-8.0 Platform Using Eclipse Development

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am trying to put sample for MFP-8.0 Apps and i follow that below links & video,

https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2016/06/17/ibm-mobilefirst-studio-8-0-plugin-for-eclipse-now-available/

This is error message i got from eclipse console.
    E:\POC\MFP-8.0\MFP\SampleTest\www>mfpdev app register --noprompt
    E:\POC\MFP-8.0\MFP\SampleTest\www>exit
    'mfpdev' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.

If anything i missed out for above the tutorial what else i have to do? kindly any one advice me.

System environment : Windows 8.1,Eclipse Mars, Java 1.8

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If it doesn't know what "mfpdev" is, it sounds like then that you do not have the MobileFirst CLI installed.

Make sure you have nodejs installed, then from command line run the following command: `npm install -g mfpdev-cli`, which will install the CLI.

The Studio plug-in relies on the CLI installed, since behind-the-scenes it calls CLI commands.